# Trouble passing variables between PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple HTML5 login page that requests a username and a password.  The information is passed via POST to PHP for comparison with data in MySQL.  I am trying to echo a simple "YES" if data was successfully validated and a "NO" otherwise.  I want to take the text value of the response and manipulate it using Javascript.  Everything seems to be working properly, but when the $response variable is echoed it is shown by itself on a blank HTML document and the JavaScript never gets executed.  Following is the code I am using :

```
<ul>
<li>
<form action="login_submit.php" id="loginTest" method="post">
<span class="un"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" id="maindata_email" name="maindata_email" value="" maxlength="40" required class="text" placeholder="Usuario"/></li>
<li>
<span class="un"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span><input type="password" id="maindata_password" name="maindata_password" value="" maxlength="10" required class="text" placeholder="Password"/></li>
<li>
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>">
<div class="up">
<input type="submit" id ='ingresar' value="ingresar" class="btn">
<!--window.alert(5 + 6);-->
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var myData = <?php echo json_encode($response); ?>;
    window.alert(myData);
    if (myData == "YES") {
        alert("Usuario aceptado!");
        var href = 'http://index2.html';
        window.location=href;
    } else {
        alert("Usuario invalido!");
        var href = 'http://index.html';
        window.location=href;       
    }
</script>
<input type="submit"  id = 'editar' value="editar" class="btn">
</form>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the PHP section :

```
 /*** bind the parameters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':maindata_email', $maindata_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':maindata_password', $maindata_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** check for a result ***/
        $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
        if ($user_id == false)
        {
                echo $response = "NO";
        }
        /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
        else
        {
                /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                /*** tell the user we are logged in ***/
                echo $response = "YES";
        }


    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
        $message = 'No se puede procesar su ingreso.  Favor de intentar mas tarde.'."<br />\r\n";
    }
}
```

After I click on ingresar in the HTML the username and password are properly sent and received by PHP, the information is properly processed and compared to the values contained in the MySQL database and I get the proper response upon validation.  Could anyone please explain why I get the blank page with the $response and the JavaScript code is never executed???  Thanx

Comment: What does your Error Log say? Error 500 as Status Code?

Comment: you have 1x `<form>` and 2x `</form>` tags, along with some missing code for your PHP.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to do what you want, there are numerous tutorials for this, especially using jquery.

Comment: and if this is your actual code `http://index.html` it's invalid.

Comment: @Bernie - What do you see in the browser address bar after clicking submit ?

Comment: I took out the first duplicate </form> tag, because I want the form action "login_submit.php" to execute when either the ingresar (accept) or the editar (edit) button is clicked.  I am using XAMPP to process my requests.  Still getting a blank page and javascript is not executing.

Comment: The browser address bar shows http://localhost/afilia2/login_submit.php after I click the submit, indicating the request was properly sent.   login_submit.php checks the username and password in the MySQL database and returns YES if found and NO if user not found.  This part is working correctly.  The YES and NO are stored in the $response variable which never gets to my js code????

Comment: I thank you all for your valuable feedback and I am hopeful that, with your help, I will eventually get my code working.  I am not posting my entire my login2.php code (which requests username and password from user on the client side) or the login_submit.php (which processes the input provided in login2.php, compares it with records in the MySQL database and assigns the YES value to $response if user is found and NO otherwise), primarily because I don't think it is necessary and also because I don't want to bother you with info that you don't really need.

Comment: I have seriously considered using AJAX to get the desired result.  I haven't because I think I would have to access the database from AJAX using XMLHttpRequest (which I am not used to doing), I believe I would have to replace my PHP code (which is already validating properly) with javascript and some js code has given me problems in Safari (it basically doesn't execute).  Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many thanx to all of you :)

Comment: I also tried these two variants without success : var myData = "<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>"; and var myData = "<?php echo json_encode($response) ?>"; - Neither of them worked with XAMPP.  Perhaps if I try it on the actual server the code will work, but I doubt it?

Comment: Praveen :  I don't think I need to look at the error log since their appears to be no error.  I am simply not able to pass a simple string value 'YES' or 'NO' from the server PHP to the client PHP.  From login_submit.php to login2.php which requests the username and password for validation through login_submit.php using XAMPP???

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be behaving as expected.  Your form, upon submission makes a POST request to the servar at `login_submit.php`, and the browser displays the response from the server, which is where you've echoed the value of `$response`.  There is no javascript or HTML printed on the PHP page, so no javascript is going to be run, and no HTML is going to be displayed... the browser is merely displaying the raw contents of the POST response from the form action since it's just interpreting it as a text response with no markup.

Now, what you're *actually* wanting is to get the data from the response on a web-page and run some javascript using that response data.  There are a couple ways you could tackle this problem:

1. Avoid a page reload by using AJAX techniques to asynchronously request data back from the server through `login_submit.php`.  When the data arrives back from the server after some indeterminate period of time, a javascript callback is called on the page which involves an action on the incoming response data.
2. Your `login_submit.php` page prints a full HTML page with the javascript embedded on that page, and you populate the variables in the resulting javascript from the PHP code that runs the MySQL query.
3. Take a page from ASP.NET forms and POST back to the page itself rather than a separate page, and use PHP to detect when a POST-back has taken place.  So all the code for the form, MySQL query, etc. exists in the same PHP document, and you POST to the page itself.  When the page reloads from the POST, it will populate the necessary javascript variables on the page with the correctly values.

Comment: Thank you Jason :)  If I understand you correctly you are suggesting I use AJAX to access the MySQL database directly from login2.php and do the username and password validation on the same page using an XMLHttpRequest.  I guess I could do this, but it would mean throwing away my login_submit.php code which was working great until I tried to pass a simple string value from one php page to another.  Is it really so difficult to perform such a simple task between the server and the client?

Comment: Jason are you suggesting that I include my js code directly in the login_submit.php which does the database validation instead of having it in my login2.php where it currently is?

Comment: Could you be a bit more code specific with regards to the AJAX techniques I should be using?

Comment: How can I use AJAX to get the $response value from login_submit.php and continue executing my js code after the submit (which is where I left off), within the login2.php file???

Comment: With PHP code there is no "server/client" ... everything happens on the server side.  The client makes a HTTP request to the server, and the server, using PHP, responds with some text ... that can be HTML/CSS/Javascript, it can be JSON, it can be XML, it can be pretty much anything.  Typically in the case of a webpage it's going to be HTML/CSS/javascript.  Right now you're just sending back a raw string ... it's not HTML, it's not javascript, it's just a string response.

Comment: So when you submit your form, and it goes to login_submit.php, that PHP page is going to have to be your new webpage ... it's going to have to print out more than a raw string response.  So yes, if you take choice #2, you're going to have to put your javascript, HTML, etc. on the login_submit.php so that page actually renders something useful for a browser client.